# Create array of items from dynamic resource in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to create an array resource of colors in XAML where each color is defined as a dynamic resource. I think that it can be done, but I can't figure out the syntax.

I have tried this:

```
<x:Array Type="Color" x:Key="Colors">
    <Color>
        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="BasicBlueColor" />
    </Color>
</x:Array>
```

But it doesn't work, because dynamic resource can only be assigned to dependency property.

And this just simply doesn't work, but I think it describes well what I am trying to do:

```
<x:Array Type="Color" x:Key="Colors">
    <Color>{DynamicResource BasicRedColor}</Color>
</x:Array>
```

Clarification:

- <s>I can't use static resources over dynamic because the colors are defined in referenced assembly which is out of my control.</s>
- The resource I am trying to create must be of type IList.

Edit 2: I was under impression that the resources are **defined** as static or dynamic and that they must be used as defined. My thanks to @Sham for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ResourceDictionary` to place multiple resources.

You may create one `ResourceDictionary` with name "ApplicationNameColors" and use these keys wherever required. Don't forget to add this to application/windows/etc `resources` before using.

`DynamicResource` is very different mechanism than the things you are talking about. It's recomended to use `DynamicResource` when your style is dependent on windows setting because `DynamicResource` may cost the application performance.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color1" Color="#555555" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color2" Color="#555555" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color3" Color="#555555" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color4" Color="#555555" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color5" Color="#555555" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my question with clarification.

Comment: @kwitee Nice, you don't need `DynamicResource` even if colors are defined in other assembly because assembly is known at compile time.

Comment: The color is defined in the other assembly as dynamic resource. Can I make it static on my end?

Comment: @kwitee Could you share the sample xaml for those dynamic resources?

Comment: Resources are not static or dynamic when you define them. Static and Dynamic are mechanism to use. Go through the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms748942(v=vs.100) for details.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You could reference the `Color` resources using `StaticResource`. This works:

```
<Color x:Key="BasicRedColor">Red</Color>
<Color x:Key="BasicGreenColor">Red</Color>
<x:Array Type="Color" x:Key="Colors">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="BasicRedColor" />
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="BasicGreenColor" />
</x:Array>
```

If you want to to be able to switch colours at runtime, you will have to replace or modify the `Color` objects in the array programmatically.

An array is an array that may or may not contain some elements. It's not some kind of dependency object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my question with clarification.

Comment: I don't understand your first remark and disagree with your second one.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible, since dynamic resource should be used for dependency property in objects derived from DependencyObject, but x:Array is not a dependencyobject, this is what error says:

> A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be used within a 'ArrayList'
>   collection. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.